# Not able to run test inside the async function in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, jestjs

I am using jest framework (`version 23.3.0`) to test javascript code , I have written a test inside the **async** function which in not getting executed.

```
function fn(){
    return new Promise((resolve,rej)=>{
                  setTimeout(()=>{
                      resolve('done');

                  },500)
              })
   }

 async function fn1(){
   let a = await fn();
    test('audienceTest',()=>{
        console.log('test')
        return fn();   
    })
  }

  fn1();
```

In case of normal function,test executed fine.

Comment: Can you make test itself async and try ? `test('audienceTest', async()=>{ let a = await fn();`

Comment: @SumanthKumarMora I have a scenario in which I am making `describe function async` and then I need to run tests but after making describe function to async test  itself not running. As we do not have any hook which can run before the describe function in jest , so i am just doing work around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some `async` function and wait before it will be finished we have to use `await` word before this function. In your example:

```
await fn1();
```